# Firebase sorting clarification on snapshot.value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Was hoping someone could help me understand Firebase snapshot and sorting. Why if you queryOrderedByChild on a FirebaseDBRef, the snapshot.value returns as displayed on the Firebase Database (using the browser), but if you do `for snap in snapshot.children{}` the values do show sorted. Just wanting clarification on why this happens.

Let me explain with example.

```
let dinoRef = rootRef.child("dino")
let query = dinoRef.queryOrderedByChild("dimensions/height")
query.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        // This prints to the console unsorted
        print(snapshot.value)

        // This prints to console sorted
        for snap in snapshot.children {
            print(snap)
        }
    })
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `FIRDataSnapshot` contains information about the keys of the returns data, the values associated with those keys and the order of the keys. When you call [`snapshot.children`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot.html#aa141d84d6f0575a3095908a1605daf4d) the snapshot the enumerator will return the children in the order you requested.

When you call [`snapshot.value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot.html#abd618080bd1b6cc92bf842ef685f2917) on a snapshot, it must convert all the information to an `NSDictionary`. A dictionary has no inherent information on the order of data, so the order of the results is lost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You must try order by child with ascending and descending option. That will clarify your doubt.

Comment: Hi, there is no ascending or descending option. As per Firebase documentation sorting is already ascending and only ascending. ---- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data#data_order . Even if there was an asc or desc option your comment doesn't clarify my question. If I print the snapshot.value the result is unsorted, if I print each Snapshot.children the result is sorted.